# Не получается считать pdf в сервлете

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, pdf, byte

Есть сервлет:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import ru.dsu.saidov.web.beans.Book;
    import ru.dsu.saidov.web.database.Database;

    public class ShowPdf extends HttpServlet {

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            int index = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
            try {
                conn = Database.getConnection();
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT content FROM Book WHERE id = ?");
                stmt.setInt(1, index);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                String s = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                File f = null;

                while (rs.next()) {

                    try {
                        f = new File(s.substring(0, s.length() - 6) + "generated/jsp/upload/" + rs.getString("content"));
    //home/admin/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/domains/domain/generated/jsp/upload/имя файла
                        System.out.println(f.exists());

                        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) f.length()];

                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

                        fis.read(bytesArray);

                        fis.close();

                        out.write(bytesArray);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        out.close();
                    }
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(ShowPdf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (stmt != null) {
                        stmt.close();
                    }
                    if (rs != null) {
                        rs.close();
                    }
                    if (conn != null) {
                        conn.close();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ShowPdf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        /**
         * Returns a short description of the servlet.
         *
         * @return a String containing servlet description
         */
        @Override
        public String getServletInfo() {
            return "Short description";
        }// </editor-fold>
    }
```

Из БД получаю имя файла, затем определяю путь к нему в ФС. Файл правильно находится, но вот pdf не получается отобразить. Но при этом никаких ошибок не вываливается. Что я не так делаю, подскажите?

Comment: А что происходит?

Comment: ничего не происходит, просто выводит на странице: "Не удалось загрузить документ PDF Перезагрузить"

Comment: С mime типом возможно надо помудрить. Вот тут есть пример отдачи файла: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-download-file-example

Comment: Вообще много материала по запросу "java servlet download file from server".

Comment: @shadow, подозреваю, что вы пытаетесь передать за один response слишком большой объём данных. В HTTP по такому поводу существует правило поддержки фрагментарного скачивания и докачки. Если ваш файл имеет вес в несколько мегабайт, посмотрите подробное описание протокола HTTP.

Comment: @test123 Вы не поверите, но по http можно передавать непрерывный бесконечный поток. Например motion jpeg.

Comment: Зачем Вы закрываете `out`? 99% что в этом проблема. Не Вы открыли его, не Вам и закрывать. Сервер его открывает и закрыть тоже должен сам, когда сочтёт нужным.

Comment: @Sergey поясните, как это противоречит тому что я сказал?

Comment: @Sergey Естественно, по http я могу передать слона и 100500 стримов аудио+видео, но, обращаю внимание на то как это сделал ТС: >>byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) f.length()];<< Вас не смущает эта попытка пропихнуть 40 метровый файлик в 1 ответ сервера? А если файлик весит 10 Гигов?

Comment: @test123 Именно одним ответом можно пихать сколь угодно много гигабайтов и тем более метров. Уж на метрах-то это точно проверено практикой.

Comment: @Sergey Хорошо, я вам поверю, значит я был не прав, но, сам так делать не буду) ИМХО, заставлять клиента подтянуть за раз большой файл, не давая ему права на задержку, таймаут или разрыв соединения - очень сурово по отношению к конечному пользователю.

Comment: ну, так все очевидно.. создали файл с каким-то именем..он, есть ? - разумеется, его же только что создали, а потом из него читаем в bytesArray и возвращаем его в виде файла.. только файл нулевой длинны.. почему? думаю, понятно - забыли данные в файл кинуть